# How to shuffle a hashmap in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have created a `hashmap`. Now I want to shuffle the objects in it. We have `Collections.shuffle()` to shuffle all the elements in a `list`. How can I do the same in hashmap?

This is my `hashmap`:

```
val tips = hashMapOf("Having a balanced diet is the key" to "Have nutritious foods like vegetables and fruits along with legumes, whole wheat, cereals etc., at regular intervals. Avoid oily and spicy food to ease your pregnancy symptoms. Plan your food intake and have it as 4-5 light meals every day."
            , "Fluids will help you manage" to "Drink sufficient water and fluids to maintain the retention of water in your body. This will help you control constipation, indigestion, dryness, fatigue, bloating and gas. Avoid alcohol and caffeine drinks which may have serious effects during pregnancy."
            , "Do not miss prenatal supplements" to "Doctors prescribe prenatal vitamin and mineral supplements for the normal growth and development. Do not skip these supplements as they can prevent preterm labour and many serious health concerns in the newborn."
            , "Folic acid is essential" to "During pregnancy, have folic acid (supplement) or folate (natural source of folic acid) to avoid various health problems. They are rich in green leafy vegetables, oranges, avocado etc.")
```

Comment: A Map doesn't have the concept of ordering, so shuffling doesn't apply. And "I want to shuffle" isn't really a reason. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @abhijit sarkar your statement, that a Map does not have a concept of ordering, is not entirely true. what you say is true for hashmaps, but not necessarily all maps. E.g. not for treemaps, which are in order internally. You are right on the sense that this is usually not exposed externally.

Comment: @leoderprofi If I wanted to talk specifically about `TreeMap`, I’d. I didn’t, because the OP is using a `HashMap`. Thanks for the Java 101 lecture that I didn’t need

Comment: @abhijit sakar You dont, but someone else coming across your comment might not have the same type of understanding. I certainly did not mean to offend you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want a random tip, but not the same one twice until the map is exhausted. For that, you should not alter the map at all. Use a singleton which provides you with random tips like that.

```
val tips = /*...*/

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val (title, text) = TipProvider.next()
  println("$title: $text")
}

object TipProvider {

  var tipPool = mutableListOf<String>()

  fun next(): Pair<String, String> {
      if(tipPool.isEmpty()) {
           // create copy of keys
           tipPool = mutableListOf(*(tips.keys.shuffled().toTypedArray()))
      }

      val nextTipKey = tipPool.first()
      tipPool.remove(nextTipKey)
      return nextTipKey to tips[nextTipKey]!!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code should work:

```
tips.map { it.key to it.value }.shuffled().toMap()
```

It converts `Map` to `List`, shuffles it and then converts back to `Map`.

Comment: Very inefficient

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar first of all I don't know why anyone would like to shuffle a map, but I provided asolution :)

Comment: Wouldn't this result in the same map?

Comment: @leaderprofi shuffle by definition does not exclude the previous ordering.